# Jquery/Javascript Datatables : How to display row data into html textfield on row selection

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, datatable

I have used the following `datatable` in my project. I have successfully populated all the data into the `datatable`.

I just need to populate a specific row data on row selection into textfields found on the same page and update those data which will then be saved in the database.

Link of datatable used: https://datatables.net/examples/api/select_single_row.html

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/o92g9goL/2/

Comment: not clear so much `populate a specific row data on row selection` what do you mean?

Comment: i need to display the data from a specific row into the textfields

Comment: the data should be displayed in the textfields when i click on a row

Comment: you mean,  when you click on a specific row, it turn to a `text input` then you can `edit data` ?

Comment: no, when i click on a specific row, the row data should be displayed into textfields(textboxes) accordingly so that i can modify them.

Comment: yes, sorry i misunderstood. any idea how can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

```
  var name = $(this).children('td[name="name"]').text();
  var position = $(this).children('td[name="position"]').text();
  var office = $(this).children('td[name="office"]').text();
  var age = $(this).children('td[name="age"]').text();
  var startdate = $(this).children('td[name="startdate"]').text();
  var salary = $(this).children('td[name="salary"]').text();

  var nameInp = $('input[name="name"]');
  var positionInp = $('input[name="position"]');
  var officeInp = $('input[name="office"]');
  var ageInp = $('input[name="age"]');
  var startdateInp = $('input[name="start"]');
  var salaryInp = $('input[name="salary"]');

  $(nameInp).attr('value',name);
  $(positionInp).attr('value',position);
  $(officeInp).attr('value',office);
  $(ageInp).attr('value',age);
  $(startdateInp).attr('value',startdate);
  $(salaryInp).attr('value',salary);
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jiffiddle/o92g9goL/3/)**

---

**It's what you want, you should use `Simple inline editing` from `dataTables.editor.min.js`:**

```
 $('#example').on( 'click', 'tbody td:not(:first-child)', function (e) {
        editor.inline( this );
    } );
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4nil/zq7j97c4/)**

**and also check this out:**

[Simple inline editing](https://editor.datatables.net/examples/inline-editing/simple)

[Bubble editing with in table row controls](https://editor.datatables.net/examples/bubble-editing/inTableControls.html)

Comment: instead of editing data on the row itself, i need to display the data in text inputs found above the table and edit from there. not from the row.

Comment: if I understand right , you want to edit a row duo a `text input` that placed above the table?

Comment: yes. I have 5 text inputs on my page and below it i have my datatable.
so, when i click on a row on the datatable, it should populate the data from that selected row into the text inputs above.

Comment: OK, first put what you have done so far in your question, such `html` and `css` etc.. update your question with your codes. let other user can solve your problem with see your codes.

Comment: here is the code: https://jsfiddle.net/o92g9goL/2/
when i click on a row in the datatable, the row data should get displayed into the text inputs above.

Comment: @N.Ni answer updated! is it what you want?

Comment: Thank you so much! Works fine.